# Can't access a type in one .ml file in another .ml file

Tags: ocaml

In my first file, `file1.ml`, I define a type `nfa = {start: int; finals: int list}`. In another file, `file2.ml`, I open the first file and try to make variable type `nfa`, but the compiler doesn't seem to like that.

**file1.ml:**

```
type nfa = {start: int; finals: int list}
...
```

**file2.ml:**

```
open File1
let regexp_to_nfa re = match re with
  | Empty_String -> {start=0; finals=[]}
...
```

The compiler throws the following error:

```
File "file2.ml", line 14, characters 21-26:
Error: Unbound record field start
```

I'm not sure what's wrong, because I `open` the module at the top of the second file. Any thoughts?

Comment: Probably you have forgotten recompiling `file1.ml` after you added the type `nfa`.

Comment: Another possibility is you defined a .mli that doesn't export the fields of your type.

Comment: @PatJ you were right - I had an mli file that hid the implementation of my type. Thank you!